# How to get last record in sqlite3 db with where condition

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying search records in sqlite3 table to get last record inserted with where condition, but I can do it with only one `condition WHERE CODE = df = "DS3243"`. But what I want to do is with multiple WHERE conditions `jf = "QS2134", df = "DS3243", sf = "MS5787"`, so that I can get the last record inserted with the codes provided.

*DEMONTSTRATION*

```
CODE              POINT

QS2134            1000

DS3244            2000

MS5787            3000

QS2134            130   

QS2134             200  # want to get this because it last with such code

DS3244             300

MS5787            4500

DS3244            860   # want to get this because it last with such code

MS5787            567   

MS5787            45009 # want to get this because it last with such code
```

Am able to do for only one variable `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PROFILE WHERE CODE=? ORDER BY POINT ASC LIMIT 1 ",(df,))` but i want to do for multiple varaiables.

```
import sqlite3


jf = "QS2134"

df = "DS3243"

sf = "MS5787"


con = sqlite3.connect("TEST.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PROFILE WHERE CODE=? ORDER BY POINT ASC LIMIT 1 ",(df,)) # limit one means last one

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)


con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the problem is. What happens when you try to extend your solution to multiple WHERE conditions?

Comment: i haven't tried that one can you help me out

Comment: I'm afraid that's difficult if I don't know what the problem is. I'd recommend checking the [SELECT documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). It explains the syntax pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but is it possible that you meant that you want to group the results?
Is it "group by" clause that you're looking for?

Something like:

```
select CODE, MAX(POINT) group by CODE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply trying to extend your query, in which case, why don't you try string formatting?

```
x = "SELECT * FROM my_table where col1 = '{0}' or col2 ='{1}';".format(var_1, var_2)
cur.execute(x)
```

That way you can extend your query with as many conditions as you like.